# how to add state param for Uberauth in Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, omniauth, ueberauth

During oAuth process it's good to set state param to authorize url for security. When I checked Überauth Shopify https://github.com/kodehort/ueberauth_shopify/blob/master/lib/ueberauth/strategy/shopify.ex#L88 it is sent to shopify.

But I don't understand how I need to set this state param in my Phoenix application that Shopify would get it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You supply `state` in the URL you're passing to Ueberauth (In the same way, `scopes` are passed as well)

Depending on your router setup, with the default being:

```
pipeline :auth do
  Ueberauth.plug "/auth"
end

scope "/auth" do
  pipe_through [:browser, :auth]

  get "/:provider/callback", AuthController, :callback
end
```

you supply `scopes` and `state` by redirecting your user to the specified auth URL:

`/auth/shopify?scopes=read_orders%20read_products&state=yourSuperSecretState`

or without any scopes:

`/auth/shopify?state=yourSuperSecretState`

Comment: oh, thanks. I thought it's possible to set somehow in a code

Comment: If the answer works for you, you should also accept it ;)

Answer (score 1):

[Since recent](https://github.com/ueberauth/ueberauth/pull/136/files), Ueberauth auto-sets and checks it for you by default, [to protect you from CSRF](https://hexdocs.pm/ueberauth/Ueberauth.Strategy.html#__using__/1-cross-site-request-forgery).